# Planning to upgrade solr 6.x to 8.x. kindly provide steps to upgrade?

Tags: solr

1. Need to migrate all indexs or upgrade the indexs
2. Is it possible 6.x to 8.x directly or 6.x to 7.x and then 7.x to 8.x

Kindly help me on this any one done

Comment: You should always go through each major version, since there may not be any support for upgrading the index file format over more than one major version. Usually you _will_ want to reindex after upgrading, since field type may change (the Trie field type has been deprecated and replaced with the point field type, but the old Trie field type is still available).

Comment: MatsLindh thanks but upgrading means how we can do ? can you give some more detail explanation. As per my understand upgrade means 2 things 1. running solr new service like mentioned below link

Comment: It depends on your setup and which versions you want to update. See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/solr-upgrade-notes.html (or the version you want to end up on) for details. For 8.x for example, the note says "If you run in SolrCloud mode, you must be on Solr version 7.3 or higher in order to upgrade to 8.x.". So that tells you that you at least have to go through 7.3 to get where you need to be. If you're not using cloud mode, it might differ - so it depends on your setup. Use the upgrade notes for the version you want to arrive on and _test it on a separate instance_ first.

Answer (score 1):

You should start reading the complete documentation provided to [upgrade to Solr 8.x from pre 7.x version](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_8/solr-upgrade-notes.html#upgrading-from-pre-7-x-versions), before starting the update process.

> When upgrading between major versions (for example, from a 7.x release to 8.x), a best practice is to always reindex your data.

When even skipping a major version, like in your case, an index migration is not supported and requires a reindexing of the complete data.